# Reporting of 1256 Based Options

Tags: united-states, income-tax, investing, options, capital-gains-tax

I live in the United States. In 2015 I have traded several 1256 based options. The details of each trade were not included in my 1099 and not imported into Turbo Tax. I understand that this is to be expected. Do I have to show the details of each trade on my 2015 tax return on form 8945? Can I just report the summary that my broker reported?

Thanks.